# R: Merging matrices by column names

Tags: r, matrix, merge

I have a basic question about the merge function.

From my understanding, merge(mat1, mat2) is supposed to merge matrices by column names, keeping those present in both matrices.

I have two tables (examples below). The row names are different but some column names are in common. I want to keep the columns that are in common:

mat1:

```
  B C D E
a x x x x
b x x x x
c x x x x
d x x x x
e x x x x
```

and mat2:

```
  B E F G
f y y y y
g y y y y
h y y y y
i y y y y
j y y y y
```

so the output is supposed to be something like:

```
    B   E
a   x   x
b   x   x
c   x   x
d   x   x
e   x   x
f   y   y
g   y   y
h   y   y
i   y   y
j   y   y
```

However, merge(mat1, mat2) returns:

```
> merge(test, testt)
[1] B E C D F G
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I must be doing something wrong. Any advice? Thank you!

Comment: I think you want `rbind(mat1[,c(1,4)],mat2[,c(1,2)])` instead?

Comment: `merge` doesn't do what you think it does. It performs a join between tables (and is often used with `data.frame`s and not with matrices). Your goal is maybe achieved with `commoncols<-intersect(colnames(mat1),colnames(mat2)); rbind(mat1[,commoncols],mat2[,commoncols])`

Comment: @aichao no, since I don't want to specify which columns are the ones in common. I will be applying this to very large tables

Comment: @nicola it seems to work, thank you!

Comment: That is ok, just do an `intersect` as @nicola suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with rbind and have it check for matching column names automatically.

If you're using a data.table you can do this:

```
DT1 = data.table(1:2,1:2)
DT2 = data.table(1:2,1:2,1:2)
rbind(DT1[,which(colnames(DT1) %in% colnames(DT2)),with = FALSE],DT2[,which(colnames(DT2) %in% colnames(DT1)),with = FALSE])
```

Output:

```
V1 V2
 1  1
 2  2
 1  1
 2  2
```

For a data.frame:

```
DF1 = data.frame(1:2,1:2)
DF2 = data.frame(1:2,1:2,1:2)
rbind(DF1[,which(colnames(DF1) %in% colnames(DF2))],DF2[,which(colnames(DF2) %in% colnames(DF1))])
```

Output:

```
X1.2 X1.2.1
   1      1
   2      2
   1      1
   2      2
```